# How to specify the NODE_ENV to test in AWS amplify

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, aws-amplify

I have a React/Node app which I am hosting on AWS amplify. I have two environments namely production and test(env.production and env.test files). I have set `NODE_ENV` to test in environment variables, but it is always pointing to production. How can I specify the `NODE_ENV` to test?

Comment: You dont do it in your react app, you go to aws amplify and go under the menu "environment variables" and set it there

Answer (score 0):

In the amplify console you can select the backend environment for each frontend environment by clicking edit.
See detailed information in [this](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-three/) guide